# ACS citation style biblatex reprint

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to cite a reprinted version of a book (using citavi) and after some research I found this suggestion by the ACS style guide:

> Maclean, D.; Baldwin, J. J.; Ivanov, V. T.; Kato, Y.; Shaw, A.; Schneider, P.; Gordon, E. M. Glossary of Terms Used in Combinatorial Chemistry (IUPAC Technical Report) Pure Appl. Chem. 1999, 71, 2349–2365; Reprinted J. Comb. Chem. 2000, 2, 562–578.

The citavi forum recommends to use the field original publication" (`origdate`) if it is supported by the citation style. However, I guess the `biblatex` package (`style=chem-acs`) does not support the field "original publication" (`origdate`).
Do you have any suggestion to include the original publication date in the citation? Or is there only one date required (if so, which one?) for the ACS style?

Comment: Welcome. AFAIK the `origdate` field is only needed if there is e.g. a later reprint which is no new edition. For example, a reprint of a book in 2020 which was original published in 1920 would use the fields `date/year=2020` and `origdate=1920`. Not all styles support that option, but many do. As long as you cite regular references which only contain one publishing date, you should not need `origdate`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I only have access to the reprinted version (which is not a new edition) and not the first publication, thus I should mention it in the references.  I just don't know if the citation style itself doesn't take reprints into account, since there is no explicit paragraph about it in the style guide, just this one reference quote from above, or if it's due to the implementation in `biblatex` style.